# Verify that the function is a solution to the differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Verify that the function:
$$u(t)=e^{t^2}\int^t_0e^{-s^2}ds+e^{t^2}$$
is a particular solution to the differential equation:
$$\frac{du}{dt}-2tu=1$$

**My Attempt**

I will verify this by differentiating the function with respect to $t$.
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dt}&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t^2}\int^t_0e^{-s^2}ds+e^{t^2}\right)\\
&=2te^{t^2}\left(\int^t_0e^{-s^2}ds\right)+e^{t^2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int^t_0e^{-s^2}ds\right)+2te^{t^2}
\end{align}
I'm having trouble solving the integral because it involves an error function. Could I get some pointers on how to evaluate this? Or is there a different way to verify that the function is a solution? Thanks

Comment: **Hint** If $f$ is continuous, $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^t f(s)ds=f(t).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to integrate the function, you can use Leibniz Integral rule( See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#:~:text=This%20formula%20is%20the%20general,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#:%7E:text=This%20formula%20is%20the%20general,)) or fundamental theorem of calculus.

Then $\displaystyle\frac{du}{dt}$ becomes

$\displaystyle\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{t^2}\int^t_0e^{-s^2}ds+e^{t^2})$

$\displaystyle=2te^{t^2}(\int^t_0e^{-s^2}ds)+e^{t^2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int^t_0e^{-s^2}ds\right)+2te^{t^2}=2te^{t^2}(\int^t_0e^{-s^2}ds)+e^{t^2}e^{-t^2}+2te^{t^2}
$

$\displaystyle=2t(e^{t^2}\int^t_0e^{-s^2}ds+e^{t^2})+1=2tu+1$

Thus $$\frac{du}{dt}-2tu=1$$

Comment: [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements) is enough ;-)

Comment: @Surb Yes :-), but Leibniz rule is more general for differentiation under the integral sign, however it can be derived from fundamental theorem